# GAM + KeepMeLoggedIn + Facebook/Google

Tags: .net, genexus, net, autenticacion

quería consultarles lo siguiente:

Tenemos una aplicación WEB (Net, Gx17u2) con GAM.

Los tipos de autenticación son local, facebook y google.

Si el usuario se autentica local y pone KeepMeLoggedIn nos funciona correctamente, sin embargo si el usuario ingresa con Facebook o google no mantiene la sesión.

La prueba que hacemos es desde el celular entrar con chrome. Si autentico local y cierro el browser (no queda ni en segundo plano) y vuelvo a abrirlo e ir a la URL funciona correctamente.

Realizando los mismos pasos pero el usuario habiendo autenticado con Google o Facebook al abrir la URL nuevamente la sesión no está iniciada.

Me estará faltando alguna configuración? O algo? Revolví la wiki buscando pero no encontré nada que tenga que configurar especialmente mas que el authentication Type.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Se libera en la U6 el fix, adjunto el SAC:
https://www.genexus.com/en/developers/websac?data=49920;;

Comment: Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción.

Comment: Por lo que dice la respuesta, entiendo que esto es un bug. Si es asi, entonces por favor aclara cual es el bug.

Answer (score 0):

Joaquin, como estas?

Actualmente el "Keep Me Logged In" de GeneXus solo funciona para los tipos de autenticación que no se redireccionan a un identity provider (IDP).

Ejemplos: local, Custom, WebService